# Does paginated report visual on a power bi report (import model) make the report composite model?

Tags: powerbi

This is about paginated report in Power BI service.

Supposing I have a power bi report in import mode.

If I add a live dataset now then the model becomes composite. It converts the connections mode to direct query for both datasets.

However, if instead of the above, I add a paginated report visual then does the report become composite model (and does connection get converted to direct query)?